# Hibernate - java.lang.Object; cannot be cast to

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I am currently tryting to get an sql query that returns me the top 10 highscores of my game into a list in java.

```
List<Hsg_Highscore> highscoreList = sessionObj.createSQLQuery("" +
                "select id, score, time_played, score_creation_date, user_id from (\n" +
                "select *, min(score_creation_date) OVER (Partition by user_id) score_creation_date_user from(\n" +
                "select *, min(time_played) OVER (Partition by user_id) time_played_user  from\n" +
                "(select id, score, time_played, score_creation_date, user_id,\n" +
                "max(score) OVER (Partition by user_id) score_user\n" +
                "from hsg_score\n" +
                ") h2\n" +
                "where score_user = score\n" +
                ") h3\n" +
                "where time_played_user = time_played\n" +
                ") h4\n" +
                "where score_creation_date_user = score_creation_date").list()
```

I basically see my highscores in my list when I debug the program, these are my highscore values:

[image: these are my highscore values]

My problem is that I cant access these Values without getting following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to
> de.dhbw.project.score.Hsg_Highscore

My attempt to get access to the data:

```
highscoreList.get(0).getScore()
```

Comment: The sql query supplied you a list of arrays with the columns but you expect it to be a list of highscores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Session.createSQLQuery` uses real SQL instead of HQL. That means it will always return a list of `Object[]` instead of mapping the results to a Java class.